# How do I connect apple pay and stripe connect to transfer funds to app users?

Tags: ios, applepay, stripe-connect

I'm trying to build an ios app where I sell physical goods using apple pay.

However, I need to transfer a portion of the sale to a salesperson for their commission.

I'm thinking of using Stripe's Connect API to do the fund transfers.

However, how in the hell would I prompt the Stripe transfer to fire on completion of the apple pay transaction ? I'm not familiar enough with either technology to figure this out and have had zero luck elsewhere online.

Comment: This sounds too broad for Stack Overflow - have you asked Stripe's support if what you want to do is possible, if it is supported and what they recommend for their framework?

Comment: I have and am awaiting their reply. I figured I'd see if anybody has any experience with this.

Comment: This goes beyond the scope of what Stripe can do out of the box, as it's really only a 1-way merchant. Consider using a Webhook from Stripe (https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types) after the Apple Pay Token is processed, then have your own method of paying the users, maybe by using PayPal's API to send money outbound to a registered email.